# pip3 install fails on mac os

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, pip, openssl

I am trying to install the ssl module using pip3 version 20.2.1 on Mac OS 10.14 which gives me the following error:

Command: pip3 install ssl

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nj/5mklr5y50b1d58zr4w_06k1c0000gp/T/pip-install-7az75aro/ssl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nj/5mklr5y50b1d58zr4w_06k1c0000gp/T/pip-install-7az75aro/ssl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/nj/5mklr5y50b1d58zr4w_06k1c0000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-9we57qa4
         cwd: /private/var/folders/nj/5mklr5y50b1d58zr4w_06k1c0000gp/T/pip-install-7az75aro/ssl/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/nj/5mklr5y50b1d58zr4w_06k1c0000gp/T/pip-install-7az75aro/ssl/setup.py", line 33
        print 'looking for', f
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is this a problem with the ssl module itself?

Comment: What was the command you used to install `ssl`?

Comment: @NoahBroyles Added the command used to the question.

Comment: You are installing the ssl package for python 2, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install the SSL package for Python 3. It is a [built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html).

The [SSL package](https://pypi.org/project/ssl/) on Pypi explains its purpose:

> The old socket.ssl() support for TLS over sockets is being superseded
> in Python 2.6 by a new ‘ssl’ module. This package brings that module
> to older Python releases, 2.3.5 and up (it may also work on older
> versions of 2.3, but we haven’t tried it).